# Zf2 application not working in localhost

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework2

I am using Apache version 2.4.18 and PHP 7. I am trying to run my zf2 application locally but when I go to url `localhost/zf2-app-folder/public` it is showing me the content of `index.php` but it should execute the index file. Then I created vhost by editing `/etc/apache2/sites-enables/000-default.conf`. The configuration is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName myServerName
     DocumentRoot /var/www/app-folder/public
     <Directory /var/www/app-folder/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and then I created the entry of `myServerName` in the hosts file but it is also showing me same `index.php` content.

Answer (score 0):

I need to install sudo apt-get intsall libapache2-mod-php and then run a2enmod php7.0. Don't forgot to restart apache